# Comparing quarterly data: Iteration in Python(Pandas) to compare multiple columns from four different excel files imported as dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, iteration

Dear Stackoverflow community,
I have an excel file **"big_excel.xlsx"**, which comprises of four columns namely **"date_column"**,**"efficacy"**, **"composition"** and **"testgroups"**. Basically, I have splitted this excel quarterly **"q1..q4**", so that I can compare values in each column with 4 different excels that I recieved from 4 different sources  which are supposed  to be 100% identical. This excels from sender are such that elements are already sorted in such way that it should match exactly with the excel which are splitted quarterly. My code works perfectly for **quarter q1**. And to compare I have used ".equals" because it can have nans. Now I have to apply same code concept for the remaining quarters **q2..q4**.

```
import pandas as pd
from os.path import expanduser as ospath
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_excel(ospath('big_excel.xlsx'))

df.date_column = pd.to_datetime(df.date_column)

df['quarters'] = df.date_column.dt.quarter

q1 = df[df.quarters == 1]

q2 = df[df.quarters == 2].reset_index(drop=True)

q3 = df[df.quarters == 3].reset_index(drop=True)

q4 = df[df.quarters == 4].reset_index(drop=True)


test_excel_q1 = pd.read_excel(ospath('from_biontech.xlsx'))

test_excel_q2 = pd.read_excel(ospath('from_astrazeneca.xlsx'))

test_excel_q3 = pd.read_excel(ospath('from_sputnik.xlsx'))

test_excel_q4 = pd.read_excel(ospath('from_moderna.xlsx'))




q1['compare_date_column'] = np.where(q1[q1.columns[1]].equals(test_excel_q1[test_excel_q1.columns[1]]), 'True', 'False')  
q1['compare_efficacy'] = np.where(q1[q1.columns[2]].equals(test_excel_q1[test_excel_q1.columns[2]]), 'True', 'False')
q1['compare_composition'] = np.where(q1[q1.columns[3]].equals(test_excel_q1[test_excel_q1.columns[3]]), 'True', 'False')
q1['compare_testgroups'] = np.where(q1[q1.columns[4]].equals(test_excel_q1[test_excel_q1.columns[4]]), 'True', 'False')
```

For this, I could obviously, change **q1-> q2,q3,q4** in `q1['compare_date_column']`, `q1['compare_efficacy']`, `q1['compare_composition']`, and `q1['compare_testgroups']`, and copy and paste. However, this is such a dirty solution and if I have increasing columns in the future, I will be very confused. So, I was wondering if my problem could be solved by iteration.

My thoughts: Create a list of variables `var_list = [q1,q2,q3,q4]` in which for each index in the var_list, it takes index i and substitutes it iteratively in

```
q1['compare_date_column'] = np.where(q1[q1.columns[1]].equals(test_excel_q1[test_excel_q1.columns[1]]), 'True', 'False')  
q1['compare_efficacy'] = np.where(q1[q1.columns[2]].equals(test_excel_q1[test_excel_q1.columns[2]]), 'True', 'False')
q1['compare_composition'] = np.where(q1[q1.columns[3]].equals(test_excel_q1[test_excel_q1.columns[3]]), 'True', 'False')
q1['compare_testgroups'] = np.where(q1[q1.columns[4]].equals(test_excel_q1[test_excel_q1.columns[4]]), 'True', 'False')
```

Do I need to define a function for this, if yes can anyone  help me, because I am still learning python. I would be very thankful for any input you provide me. Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: Maybe instead of spliting ```df``` for each quarter you could [```append```](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) or [```pd.concat```](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) together the test dataframes and then compare the resulting test dataframe with the first ```df```

Comment: Thanks for the  reply. Yes, that could be a solution too. This is just an example. In my real company scenario, we have splitted test environments in 4 different instances. And everytime, the data from big excel is splitted into quarters and pumped into each instance. Then the data is validated with the script one by one in each instance (jumping tunnels, connections, and instances). It is very difficult to etract this excel out of each environment to be concatenated or appended. Sorry, if I confuse you. Anyways, I would also like to learn how to iterate in the given scenario I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be defining a function which takes one quarter dataframe and the corresponding test dataframe for that quarter and returns the original dataframes with the comparing columns.
Something like:

```
# you can also use this function to compare just one quarter
def compare_quarter(df_q:pd.DataFrame, df_test_q:pd.DataFrame):
    # this do exactly the same as your 4 comparing code lines
    df_q[[
        'compare_date_column',
        'compare_efficacy',
        'compare_composition',
        'compare_testgroups'
    ]] = \
        [np.where(df_q.iloc[:, i].equals(df_test_q.iloc[:, i]), 'True', 'False') for i in range(1,5)]

    return df_q
```

And then you just iterate the function over the quarters:

```
for q, t in zip([q1, q2, q3, q4], [test_excel_q1, test_excel_q2, test_excel_q3, test_excel_q4]):
    q = compare_quarter(q, t)
```

Note:
I've noticed when you compare each column, you are comparing the quarter and the test columns as a whole. That means: if just only one row is different, the whole `compare_column` (all rows) will be `False`. If you want to compare element-wise, use the method [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) instead in a function like:

```
def compare_quartals(df_q:pd.DataFrame, df_test_q:pd.DataFrame):
    comp_cols = [
        'compare_date_column',
        'compare_efficacy',
        'compare_composition',
        'compare_testgroups'
    ]

    for i in range(1,5):
        df_q[comp_cols[i-1]] = df_q.iloc[:, i].eq(df_test_q.iloc[:, i])

    return df_q
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the answer! Helps me immensely!